# Group By cause non object

Tags: mysql, sql, codeigniter

I'm using codeigniter and I'm trying to perform a query execution passing a where clause, this `where` is an array, this is my code:

```
$now = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$this->record_model->getAllRecord(array('guid' => $guid,
                                 'end_datetime <' => $now,
                                 'GROUP BY hash'));
```

this is the content of `getAllRecord`

```
$query = $this->db
                ->select('*')
                ->from('appointments')
                ->where($where_clause) 'is passed as parameter..
                ->get()->result_array();
```

this is the content of `where`

```
array(3) {
["guid"]=>
string(36) "c3682d6f-75b2-4686-966d-cb3c9344369b"
["end_datetime <"]=>
string(19) "2016-01-21 12:03:58"
[0]=>
string(13) "GROUP BY hash"
}
```

Now if I remove the Group by all working well, but if I insert the `Group By hash` for don't have (duplicate) in the result this error appear:

> Call to a member function result_array() on a non-object

Essentially I want get the information of all records but some records have the same hash, so the GROUP BY should join this record in one. But I did something wrong...

Comment: group by is not part of the where clause, you should add it as `->group_by(...)`.

Comment: ok I inserted the group_by in the method and seems working, the problem is that I get 1 response with two record inside I should get two response or anyway the number response as record available by the same hash

Comment: This is a different question to what you asked.

Answer (score 1):

Group by is not part of the where clause, therefore codeigniter will generate a syntactically incorrect code, therefore `->get()` call does generate a proper resultset. You should add the group by clause using a separate `->group_by(...)` call to your query.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$query = $this->db->select('*')
            ->where($where_clause)
            ->get('appointments');
$result = $query->result_array();
return $result;
```

Comment: @SalvatoreFucito check this